# Usecase Plantuml - Vertically stack the components

Tags: use-case, plantuml, use-case-diagram

I'm trying to link the same object to multiple objects within the box.
But the objects within the box are laying horizontally instead of vertical.

```
 :Application:
    rectangle Set{

      Application-right--> (Set Property)
      (Set Property)-right..> (Sensor Property) : <<extends>>
      (Set Property)-right..> (Info Property) : <<extends>>
    (Set Property) .right..> (Audio Property) : <<extends>>
    (Set Property) .right..> (Car navigation Property) : <<extends>>
    (Set Property) .right..> (Cluster Property) : <<extends>>
    (Set Property) .right..> (Diagnostic Property) : <<extends>>
    (Set Property) .right..> (HVAC Property) : <<extends>>
    (Set Property) .right..> (Power Property) : <<extends>>
    (Set Property) .right..> (Vendor extension Property) : <<extends>>
    }
```

[image: Current output]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is horizontal, because you are explicitly telling it to be horizontal with
`.right..>`

Change it to `.down..>` and you'll get what you want.

[image]

Also note that right and down directions are the default ones and depend on the number of dashes/dots in the line specification. Compare the following:

```
@startuml 
rectangle Set1 {
  Application1 -> (Set Property1)
}

rectangle Set2 {
  Application2 --> (Set Property2)
}

rectangle Set3 {
  Application3 ---> (Set Property3)
}
@enduml
```

[image]